# Modelstate validation always return false using a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

**NOTE: Code updated to take into account the comments and answer made below.**

In my MVC app I need sometimes to make references to other objects (like a many-to-many relationship, or one-to-many relationship).

So I have this model:

```
public class ObjInfo
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obj ID is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "ObjID")]
        public int m_Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Obj Name is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Obj Name")]
        public string m_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Obj Number")]
        public int m_Number { get; set; }

        (...)

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Other Obj is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "OtherObj")]
        public int m_OtherObjID { get; set; }

        public OtherObjInfo m_OtherObj { get; set; }

        (...)
    }
```

I have default and parameters constructors as well and can show them as needed, though I am not sure if they are at fault. Anyway.

In my controller, I have the two create methods following MVC methods:

```
        //
        // GET: /Obj/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.List = new SelectList(PopulateDDLs(), "OtherObj", "Other obj ID");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Obj/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Objinfo obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                m_ObjManager.CreateObj(obj);
                return RedirectToAction("SearchIndex");
            }

            ViewBag.List = new SelectList(PopulateDDLs(), "OtherObj", "Other obj ID");
            return View(obj);
        }
```

And, finally, here's how my "Create" view is coded:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ObjInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>OBJ</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_Id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_Id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_Number)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.m_Number)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_Number)
        </div>

        (...)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_OtherObj , "Other Obj")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList(model => model.m_OtherObjID, ViewBag.List as SelectList, "--- Select Other Obj ---", new {@class = "OtherObjInfo "})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_OtherObj)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Basically, the problem is that each time I click on the "create" button, the ModelState validation is always false for the OtherObj even if something is selected in the dropdownlist. Every other values are correct except this one.

I don't understand why and I would greatly appreciate your help on this one, thank you for your help!

After code edited **

Now I get a crash as I enter the "Create" view:

```
DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'OtherObj'.
```

Exactly on the line where my dropdownlistfor is located.

The datavalueField and dataTextField are supposed to refer to what exactly?

Comment: what is the difference between your dropdown helper and other helpers?

Comment: Err, none, currently it displays the name of the OtherObj (if I understood your question well)

Comment: it didn't occur to you that every other helper has a **For** in it is a difference?

Comment: tightly bound relationships are "tighter"

Comment: Oh, ok! I'm using DropDownList, and not DropDownListFor. I saw them, but I have yet to figure out how they work. I must be honest on that.

Comment: Thats just the cosmetic hint. No lambda, and no tight association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `otherObjectId` to your model

```
public class ObjInfo
{
    public int m_Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Other Obj is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "OtherObj")]
    public int otherObjectId { get; set; }

    public OtherObjInfo m_OtherObj { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.List = new SelectList(PopulateDDLs(), "Id", "Name"); 
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Objinfo obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        m_ObjManager.CreateObj(obj);
        return RedirectToAction("SearchIndex");
    }

    ViewBag.List = new SelectList(PopulateDDLs(), "Id", "Name"); 
    return View(obj);
}
```

view

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.m_OtherObj , "Other Obj")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.otherObjectId, ViewBag.List as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---", new { @class = "some_class" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.m_OtherObj)
</div>
```

better way is using strongly typed helpers. All your helpers are `strongly-typed` (editorfor, textboxfor, dropdownlistfor,...) except dropdownlist.

if you want to bind DDL value to your model, You should use `dropdownlistfor` instead of `dropdownlist`.

your model state is not valid, because you dont bind required value as DDL to model.

Comment: I'll try this, I will get you back on the results.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the word, Dave ;) I do understand your point, though. You are right, as is @AliRiza. :)

Comment: Ok, I re-written everything, but I get a crash when the create view is done: "DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'."

Comment: You should write otherObject Text and Id. I mean Name is text and Id is value.

Comment: `new SelectList(PopulateDDLs(), "otherObjectPrimaryKey", "otherObjectNameOrText");`

Comment: Ok, I don't get it. The first parameters is the dataValueField, and the second is the dataTextField, but they are referring to what exactly? What sould I write there?

Comment: What properties are there in you OtherObjInfo ?

Comment: [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Other Obj Id")]
        public int m_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Other Obj Name")]
        public string m_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Other Obj Symbol")]
        public string m_SymbolText { get; set; }

Comment: `new SelectList(PopulateDDLs(), "m_Id", "m_Name");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24845/discussion-between-herve-simard-and-aliriza-adiyahsi)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I'm nearly done with this. But I still have a question.
I want to know why now my ModelState.IsValid comes true, but the m_OtherObjInfo is null?

Comment: there is required field in your model and you pass it with null value, Now you select it from a dll and not null, so you get true